# Changing TOP rows parameter from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, parameters, code-behind

I know we can add parameter for query `Select * from abc where xyz=@xyz` using `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xyz",xyz)`from C# code. But is it possible to change top rows paramenter for query like `Select TOP @rows * from abc where xyz=@xyz` like `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rows",32)`?

Because whenever I tried it, it showed me this exception: `Incorrect syntax near '@rows'.`

Comment: Syntax errors do not belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can defintely pass a integer into the top clause.  You should be able to do something like this.

```
select top (@Rows) *
from dbo.MyTable
order by something
```